# How should Dexie.js (v 2.0.1) database be used in Safari 10.1.2 and later?

Tags: javascript, safari, indexeddb, dexie

It works fine in Chrome, but nothing happens in Safari.

I am using it like this:

```
const deviceUserData = new Dexie('deviceUserData')

 deviceUserData.version(1).stores({  userData: 'userName, data'})
 deviceUserData.open()
 .then(result =>{
           console.log('open own DB, data:', result)  // doesn't happen
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
           console.error('Uh oh : ' + error)          // doesn't happen
 });
```

How do I access the database in Safari 10 and later?

Answer (score 0):

Dexie works with Safari 10.1 and above. Your sample should not be any problem. However, there might be other factors playing in such as:

- the db was created in your browser in an earlier version and browser was upgraded. Safari may have a bug triggered if so.
- using Dexie from within an iframe.
- including dexie.js from a cdn (different origin)
- serving your html page from file system instead of over http
- the use of indexeddbshim?

Comment: Thanks for answering. The only thing i am not sure is the first and last points you made. What would be the way to reset the db to newer version? Also, if you could find a bit of time to have a look here https://shopp.glitch.me  what might be the problem, I would really appreciate it. using dexie starts at line 100 in script whose name ends with '4e1e9.js'
I think once i manage to get that console.log thing telling me something when i open the db, i'll know how to deal with rest..